# Polynomials vanishing at origin are discrete

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of all complex functions endowed with the uniform topology. Then the set:

$A=\{p\in X\mid p\text{ is a polynomial and } p(0)=0\}$ is discrete in $X$.

It suffices to show that any singleton is open. For a given $p\in A$ the family:

$V_{p,n} = \{f\in X\mid \forall x \in \mathbb{C}: \lvert f(x)-p(x)\rvert<\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a fundamental system.

My idea is to show that $A\cap V_{p,n}$ only contains $p$, hence the singleton $\{p\}$ is open. But I cannot show this fact. Any hints?

Comment: There are not that many bounded polynomials with value $0$ at the origin.

Comment: What do you mean by bounded? We know they are all divisible by the polynomial $x$

Comment: What do you mean by the uniform topology?

Comment: $U \subseteq X$ open iff $\forall f\in U \exists \varepsilon>0 : \{g\in X \mid \forall x\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert < \varepsilon \} \subseteq U$ Not really the $L^\infty$ norm bc functions can be unbouded

Comment: Imagine a polynomial $f(x)=x$ and its small open neighborhood. What other polynomials are in it? $f(x)=1.1x$ isn't. $f(x)=x+0.1$ is, but it does not vanish at origin. So...

Comment: The zero polynomial is in $A$, hence any other polynomial in $A$ is bounded. How many bounded polynomials are there that are bounded and have value $0$ at the origin?

Comment: In every example it is clear to me where we use the vanishing at 0. However in a formal argument, what goes wrong here: let $g \in A\cap V_{p,n}$ for all $n\geq 1$ (probably here?) then $g$ gets arbitrarily close to $f$. Thus $g=f$